# Laravel multi-nested same route parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I creating internet-marketn on Laravel 5.2
Need to do something like a breadcrumps in url with categories slug,

like so

/catalog/{category_1}/{category_2}/{category_n}

but get only last parameter and bind it into Model

moreover last category can has product slug and route can be like

/catalog/{category_1}/{category_2}/{category_n}/product/{product_slug}

my routing

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'catalog'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'shop_catalog', 'uses' => 'CatalogController@catalog']);

    Route::group(['prefix' => '{category}'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'shop_show_category', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@category']);

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'product/{product}'], function () {
            Route::get('/', ['as' => 'shop_show_product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@product']);
});
```

Try write pattern in RouteServiceProvider like

```
$route->pattern('category', '.*');
```

Then explode by '/' and get last element for binding. But can't get product parameter.

How can I do this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of your routes is really important.

As the `shop_show_category` route is listed first, the router never gets to check if the url more specifically matches your `shop_show_product` route.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{category}'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'product/{product}'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'shop_show_product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@product']);
    });
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'shop_show_category', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@category']);
});
```

By rearranging so the more specific route is first, you know the router will check the `shop_show_product` route for a match first. Failing it seeing `product/xxx` at the end of the url it will try to match the `shop_show_category` route.